# Saving context.getImageData to a sessionStorage with html5?

Tags: html, canvas, session-storage

I try this, but I don't succeed. Is there a posibility to save that object or their values and then use it , e.g. for a redraw?

Comment: What did you try (what is your code)? Why didn't you succeed (what errors did you get)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the image data array (which is uncompressed), I would suggest using [`Canvas.toDataURL`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) to get a base64-encoded PNG for the canvas, and saving that string.

Later, you can [draw this data URL to your canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas).