# How can I get a canvas image into a function?

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
 var formElement2 = document.getElementById("recImage");
 formElement2.addEventListener('click', recImagePressed, false);

 function recImagePressed(e){
     var outputCanvas = document.getElementById("outputCanvas");
     outputCtx = outputCanvas.getContext('2d');
     outputCTX.draw();
     outputCtx.drawImage(canvas2, 0, 0);
 }

 function draw() {   
            img = new Image();  
            **img.src = context2.canvas2.toDataURL();** 
            fr1 = makeFrame(context2, makeVect(400,0), makeVect(400, 0), makeVect(0, 400));
            img.onload = function(){ 
                context2.save(); 
                newPainter = cornerSplit(imagePainter,5);
                newPainter(fr1);     
                context2.restore();
                context2.save();
                newPainter(flipHorizLeft(fr1));
                context2.restore();
                context2.save();
                newPainter(flipVertDown(fr1));  
                context2.restore();
                context2.save();
                newPainter(flipVertDown(flipHorizLeft(fr1)));   
            }  
        }
```

I think the problem lies here: img.src = context2.canvas2.toDataURL();

the methods that are being called have been tested and work independently of this particular block of code.

Comment: any information on the used language would be very helpfull ... java?

Comment: everything is javaScript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a variable named `context2` declared anywhere. This is the (first) reason that what you have doesn't work.

What are you trying to do? [Draw an image to a canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas)

Comment: What Im trying to do - Using these .js functions [link](http://edison.suu.edu/~grady/functional-javascript/picture-language.html)

Comment: @Phrogz--using the above functions on a user created image-->Heres what I have working, maybe seeing this will help-- Thanks [link](http://mcgrawtheseeker.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
img.src = context2.canvas2.toDataURL();
```

doesn't make any sense. A canvas context doesn't have a property called `canvas2`. Either use the variable `canvas2` if it exists or use `context2.canvas`.

Its hard to tell what you want to do since img isn't even used, but if you are trying to draw one canvas to another at some point you can use `drawImage` with a canvas as the argument, so if thats what you're trying to do you don't have to make an image and use toDataUrl at all.

Comment: I have the user generated canvas image in one window, I want to be able to retrieve that image, run through the abouve 'draw' function when the user clicks the recImagePressed button-- you can see whats working so far at [link](http://mcgrawtheseeker.com/)---thanks for responding