# tainted canvas, cross-origin data

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to get color data from an image on the web using [color-thief.js](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/).

```js
myImage = $('#myImage');
dominantColor = getDominantColor(myImage);
paletteArray = createPalette(myImage, 10);
```

Chrome is complaining about safety issues:

```
Unable to get image data from canvas because 
the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrcactu5/d6Qka/). (Why does it have two apples when I only have one `<img>` tag??)

This question has been addressed before, but I couldn't understand it.
e.g. [Drawing an image from a data URL to a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas) which seems specific to HTML5 Canvas.