# HTML5 canvas, save jpeg blob and restore to canvas from blob

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas `#mycanvas` which contains an image. I want to create a blob out of that image, preferably as a jpeg. Here is how i create the blob

```
document.getElementById('mycanvas').toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "")
```

How do i recreate the image from this blob, and show it in `#mycanvas` again?

Comment: Check out the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas

Comment: May I suggest that the word "blob" is probably a little misleading ? As shown on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) the right way to convert a `<canvas>` content into a `Blob` is to use the `.toBlob()` method, not at all `.toDataURL()`. In fact your question should have probably been _HTML5 canvas, save jpeg __data URL__ and restore to canvas from __data URL__._ What do you think ?

Comment: A data URL is a base64 representation of the image not a Blob. As danidemi pointed out. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how i solved my problem

```
function blob2canvas(canvas,blob){
    var img = new Img;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    img.src = blob;
}
```

The blob was received when calling `canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg")`

Comment: How can I do the opposite? Get the blob from canvas?

Comment: @EnriMR `document.getElementById('mycanvas').toDataURL("image/jpeg")`

Comment: @AntonGildebrand, isn't the right way to convert a canvas into a proper `Blob` the [toBlob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method ?

Comment: This is no longer accurate, you have to create a url from the blob

`img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);`

Answer (score 2):

Anton's answer no longer works as it is. You need this syntax now.

```
function blob2canvas(canvas,blob){
    var img = new window.Image();
    img.addEventListener("load", function () {
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    });
    img.setAttribute("src", blob);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Restore to Canvas from Blob sample taken from: https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/image-capture/grab-frame-take-photo.html

```
// ms is a MediaStreamPointer
let imageCapture = new ImageCapture(ms.getVideoTracks()[0]);

                imageCapture.takePhoto()
                    .then(blob => createImageBitmap(blob))
                    .then(imageBitmap => {
                        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
                        drawCanvas(canvas, imageBitmap);
                    })

function drawCanvas(canvas, img) {
    canvas.width = getComputedStyle(canvas).width.split('px')[0];
    canvas.height = getComputedStyle(canvas).height.split('px')[0];
    let ratio = Math.min(canvas.width / img.width, canvas.height / img.height);
    let x = (canvas.width - img.width * ratio) / 2;
    let y = (canvas.height - img.height * ratio) / 2;
    canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height,
        x, y, img.width * ratio, img.height * ratio);
}
```