# AngularJS decode Base64 String to png

Tags: angularjs

I am working with AngularJS and I faced a problem that I want to decode a Base64 String to a png image in AngularJS what should I do?

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `<canvas>` element and use dataUrl as source

See this questions [dataUrl to Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas)