# I can't drawimage to canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I retrieve a user from the database who has profile picture. This picture is base64 and drawImage to the canvas. but it failed to draw.

Here's my code:

```
 var userId = {'userId' : 1};
 $scope.user = UserProfileService.getUserProfile.query(userId, function() {
      var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvasweb");
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var image = new Image();
      image.onload = function() {
          ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      };
      image.src = $scope.user.profilePic;
  });
```

Please help.

Comment: Try setting the src before setting onload

Comment: @cdosborn, sir, i had already tried, it can't

Comment: Log `$scope.user.profilePic` to verify

Comment: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAP0AAAEkCAYAAADkczevAAAgAElEQVR4nOy9Z5Rc5ZXvjQNBUudUOeecc-jqrs4556BOaqmVs0ARoQTKCQEiyQQhJARIYMDYZmyMB3uwx56xx-MwY49n7l3r_fS-694ZpE71ez-UuiVsMHjuXWsGo_9ae_WprlNVJ_2eZz97P2efO7itj1UqNUMqNQPM3rCPWeeGzdyyPGc3PzcNTJNi9obd_Mz0x3zu5uc__rc-bb0_ax9v2FTq5vYATE1NzW__zPQk3HIsZklxbfL6jfVTTM6mP_vhdIopYBL495kU14EPZ2ByBqZTMDsLs6n0cZma_A9IQWrm5u9Pz86ktyc1w-xs-pj............

Comment: @cdosborn , base64 string is correct. i already checked.

Comment: according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4776378/1213041) you're method should work. You need to verify what is/isn't working. Check to make sure the canvas has a width, that is in the forefront, etc.

Are you getting any js errors?

Comment: @cdosborn i didn't get any js errors or exceptions. i will recheck again. thanks

Comment: [Exception... "Component is not available" nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8080/nomunoli/js/app/controllers.js :: $scope.user</image.onload :: line 1187" data: no] .

i now get this exceptions, when i draw with width and height

Comment: That means your src attr. Is faulty.