# How do i get a JS ID to be the background page of a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code in the .js file that allows me to stream an image:

```
//Image streamaing!
function onMessage2(evt) {
  $("#image").attr('src',  'data:image/jpg;base64,'+evt.data);
}
```

I then display it in a rectangle in html like so:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
 <img id="image" src=""> 
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 
</div>
```

The problem I have is that I need the stream to be displayed in the background of the canvas, so I can catch mouse/touch input for some other work I need.

I've tried switching the order (canvas first then image) but then all I get is a big blank screen.

Comment: please look here how to draw an image to a canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the parent relative position and absolute position for the childs then canvas will overlay the img
:

```
.row{position: relative;}
.row img, .row canvas{position:absolute; top:0; left:0;}

<div class="row" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px">
 <img id="image" src=""> 
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put the img inside the canvas. Set the width and height to 100% so it takes up all the space in the canvas and then set it's position to fixed and it's z-index to -1 so it stays out of the flow and is in the background. Here's the css code:

```
#image {
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

And don't forget to put the img in the canvas.

Comment: Thank you!! It resized the stream perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

What about making it as background image using css

```
<div id="main">
```

```
$("#main").css("background- image",  "url(url of image)");
```

Sorry for formatting i'm writing from my mobile but you might get idea