# Get image Data from a <div> CSS style in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a css style which in its background it has an image for example it is like this code

```
.test {
    background-image: url("paper.gif");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

well I also have a javascript code which is used to get average color of an image,

```
function getAverageRGB(imgEl) {

    var blockSize = 5, // only visit every 5 pixels
        defaultRGB = {r:0,g:0,b:0}, // for non-supporting envs
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'),
        data, width, height,
        i = -4,
        length,
        rgb = {r:0,g:0,b:0},
        count = 0;

    if (!context) {
        return defaultRGB;
    }

    height = canvas.height = imgEl.naturalHeight || imgEl.offsetHeight || imgEl.height;
    width = canvas.width = imgEl.naturalWidth || imgEl.offsetWidth || imgEl.width;

    context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);

    try {
        data = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
    } catch(e) {
        /* security error, img on diff domain */alert('x');
        return defaultRGB;
    }

    length = data.data.length;

    while ( (i += blockSize * 4) < length ) {
        ++count;
        rgb.r += data.data[i];
        rgb.g += data.data[i+1];
        rgb.b += data.data[i+2];
    }

    // ~~ used to floor values
    rgb.r = ~~(rgb.r/count);
    rgb.g = ~~(rgb.g/count);
    rgb.b = ~~(rgb.b/count);

    return rgb;
    }
```

As the above code shows I have to pass an image element into the function, but In fact I do not have any  tag and I only have a div which its css has a background image, How can I read  the images data?
thansk

Comment: Can I assume that `paper.gif` has transparency?

Comment: @yes if it makes it easier, it can also be a png or jpg

Comment: Research how to read styles from elements dynamically (getComputedStyle), and then once you got the image URL, _create_ a new `Image` object in JavaScript, assign the URL as `src`, and then work from there in the image `load` handler ...

Comment: Couldn't you just fill the canvas with the background color (in this case it's `#cccccc`) before applying `context.drawImage(imgEl, 0, 0);`?

Comment: @CBroe well I have never thought on this method, but does this method downloads image twice?

Comment: @JosephMarikle I did not try it, does it work?

Comment: _"but does this method downloads image twice?"_ - nope, that's what the  cache is for ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the function getAverageRGB to draw the image from the url in the background of the div, then you just pass your div and the modified function will draw the image onto the canvas - see docs below.

This question solves that problem

[Drawing an image from a data URL to a canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas)

Comment: Thanks I tried to load image.src using an image linke but it returned a black color, It seems I am doing sth wrong

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Image element using yours div background-img as source.

```
img = new Image();
img.src = divTest.style.backgroundImage;
```