# How to save a HTML Canvas content to Google Storage

Tags: javascript, django, google-cloud-platform, html5-canvas, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to save an html canvas content to Google Storage. What I do is as following :

1. Create a signed url for the image file.

> ```
> class ThumbnailUploadSignedURL(APIView):
> @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/login/'))
>     def post(self, request):
>         filename = request.POST.get('filename')
>         filetype = request.POST.get('type')
>         filesize = request.POST.get('size', 0)
>         path =  '{0}-{1}/{2}/'.format(request.user, request.user.id, thumbnail.name)
>         blob = default_storage.open(full_path, 'wb')
>         signed_url = blob.blob.generate_signed_url(expiration=default_storage.expiration, method='PUT', content_type='image/png')
>         return Response({"thumbnail_signed_url":signed_url})
> ```

2. Get the content of canvas and send it to Google Storage.

> ```
> var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
> const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
> xhr.open("PUT", data.thumbnail_signed_url, true);
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
> xhr.send(image);
> ```

The file is successfully being created on Google Storage, however the content is stated as corrupt, it is indeed basically base64.

I also tried ways to convert base64 to png, yet unsuccesfully, as it was suggested here [php-js-canvas example](https://permadi.com/2010/10/html5-saving-canvas-image-data-using-php-and-ajax/).

How can I achieve this with js and google storage ?

Comment: Hi, are you using the [HTML5 Canvas drawing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)? Have you configured CORS when uploading files to Cloud Storage? Check out the following [documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/build/web-app#cors)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have already been successfully uploading a lot of other content from the same application to Google Storage including videos . That is correct I am using Canvas drawing. By the way, the file is being created in Google Storage, but always the same size, and in base64, not as a PNG.

Comment: Have yout tried using `.toBlob()`? Check out the following [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob). Why is it corrupted? Do you get any error messages that you can share with us? I believe that using `.toDataURL()` the canvas will be base64 encoded as a humongous string, as per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL).

Comment: That is correct when I use the .toDataURL(), the canvas will be base64, it is not actually corrupt but unusable. I don't have any mechanism in Google Storage part, when the base64 file is uploaded, it is still base64, I cannot translate it to png. That is where I am stuck.

Comment: Check out the following [canvas2image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image) library that shows you how to convert canvas to images. Also, this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas) mentions how you can draw a base64-encoded image onto a canvas, in case you need it.

Comment: Thanks @sllopis, if you write this as a answer below, I can accept this as the answer.

Comment: @SuperEye, How did you solve this, I have base65 using  canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); and it is a valid base 64 i checked with online, I have a common method to upload base64 to gs, but here base64 after loaded there is a small squre image. the common method is correct its being used many place to upload image like file uploader

Comment: It's complicated, I will try to provide detailed instructions soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following [canvas2image library](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image) that shows you how to convert canvas to images.

Also, his [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas) mentions how you can draw a base64-encoded image onto a canvas using the [drawImage() method](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage), in case you need it.