# Why does drawImage from localStorage not work?

Tags: javascript, typescript, image, canvas, drawimage

Using TypeScript, but I don't think that matters.

StackOverflow new tag needed: localstorage

If you copy an img tag to a canvas through .drawImage, it works fine. If you save and load it from localStorage, you get:

drawImage: Argument 1 could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.

[Setup in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dustin_00/nb1j3fw0/24/)

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <img id="img0" src='https://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/fxxj3ttftm5ltcqnto1o4baovyl.png' height='100' width='100'>
  <canvas id="img1" height='100' width='100' style='border:1px solid #d3d3d3;'></canvas>
  <canvas id="img2" height='100' width='100' style='border:1px solid #d3d3d3;'></canvas>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const img = document.querySelector("#img0");
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous'); // mark image as safe for toDataURL

document.querySelector("#img0").onload = () => {
  saveImg('img0');
};

function saveImg(srcImgID) {
    // save img0 to local storage
  var imgSrc = document.getElementById(srcImgID);
  localStorage.setItem('someStorageKey', imgSrc);

    // copy img0 => img2
  var canvas2: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('img2') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log('cavas2: ' + canvas2);
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.drawImage(imgSrc, 0, 0);

    // load img0
  var img0: HTMLImageElement = localStorage.getItem('someStorageKey') as HTMLImageElement;
  console.log('Image data loaded: ' + img0);

    // copy img0 => img1
  var canvas1: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('img1') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log('cavas1: ' + canvas1);
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  ctx1.drawImage(img0, 0, 0); //error: Argument 1 could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement...
}
```

Comment: As per the tag, you can put that in [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or wait for [1.5K reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution, at least in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Dustin_00/nb1j3fw0/70/

@Rojo's solution works as well. But neither work inside my .NET Core app -- just a blank image.

```
<div id="app">
  <img id="img0" src='https://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/fxxj3ttftm5ltcqnto1o4baovyl.png' height='100' width='100'>
  <canvas id="canvas1" height='100' width='100' style='border:2px solid #00f;'></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" height='100' width='100' style='border:2px solid #f00;'></canvas>
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
const img = document.querySelector("#img0");
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous'); // mark image as safe for toDataURL

document.querySelector("#img0").onload = () => {
  saveImg('img0');
};

function getBase64Image(img) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;

  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

  return dataURL;
}

function saveImg(srcImgID) {
    // save img0 to local storage
  var imgSrc = document.getElementById(srcImgID);
  var imgBase64 = getBase64Image(imgSrc);
  localStorage.setItem('someStorageKey', imgBase64);

    // copy img0 => canvas2 (red border)
  var canvas2: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas2') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  //console.log('cavas2: ' + canvas2);
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.drawImage(imgSrc, 0, 0);

  // load img0
  var imgData = localStorage.getItem('someStorageKey');

  // copy img0 => canvas1 (blue border) from storage
  var canvas1: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('canvas1') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  //console.log('cavas1: ' + canvas1);
  var ctx1 : HTMLCanvasElement = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  //console.log('ctx1: ' + ctx1);
  
  var imgFromStorage = new Image(); 
  imgFromStorage.onload = function () {
    //console.log('imgFromStorage: ' + imgFromStorage);
    //console.log('imgFromStorage.src: ' + imgFromStorage.src);
    ctx1.drawImage(imgFromStorage, 0, 0);
  }
    imgFromStorage.src = imgData;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the whole element in `localStorage`, you have to use `imgSrc.outerHTML`

```
localStorage.setItem('someStorageKey', imgSrc.outerHTML);
```

Then get the element a special way: [(DOMParser MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448876/10210841)

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(localStorage.getItem('someStorageKey') as HTMLImageElement, "text/html").body.childNodes[0];
```

And wait for the image to load:

```
img0.onload = () => {
  ctx1.drawImage(img0, 0, 0);
}
```

And for some reason, I need to append the image to `<body>` for it to work. If this happens to you as well, you can just remove the image immediately (it might JSFiddle):

```
document.body.append(img0);img0.remove();
```

Full code:

```
const img = document.querySelector("#img0");
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin','anonymous'); // mark image as safe for toDataURL

document.querySelector("#img0").onload = () => {
  saveImg('img0');
};

function saveImg(srcImgID) {
    // save img0 to local storage
  var imgSrc = document.getElementById(srcImgID);
  localStorage.setItem('someStorageKey', imgSrc.outerHTML);

    // copy img0 => img2
  var canvas2: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('img2') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log('cavas2: ' + canvas2);
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.drawImage(imgSrc, 0, 0);

    // load img0
  var img0: HTMLImageElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(localStorage.getItem('someStorageKey') as HTMLImageElement, "text/html").body.childNodes[0];
  console.log('Image data loaded: ' + img0);

    // copy img0 => img1
  var canvas1: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('img1') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log('cavas1: ' + canvas1);
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
    img0.onload = () => {
    ctx1.drawImage(img0, 0, 0);
  }document.body.append(img0);img0.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage.setItem only takes strings so anything that is not a string will have `.toString()` ran on it before beeing saved, check out MDN [localStorage.setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

Have you considerd saving the img src to localStorage and doing something like this to render it https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776378/12523447

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an `img` html element you should store in `localStorage` just its `src` attribute. Then you just need to create an image set its `src` to value that is stored in localStorage and after it will be loaded draw it on `canvas`. Like so:

```
function saveImg(srcImgID) {
    // save img0 to local storage
  var img = document.getElementById(srcImgID);
  var imgSrc = img.getAttribute('src');
  
  localStorage.setItem('someStorageKey', imgSrc);

    // copy img0 => img2
  var canvas2: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('img2') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log('cavas2: ' + canvas2);
  var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  var canvas1: HTMLCanvasElement = document.getElementById('img1') as HTMLCanvasElement;
  console.log('cavas1: ' + canvas1);
  var ctx1 = canvas1.getContext('2d');
  
  // load img0
  var img0Src = localStorage.getItem('someStorageKey') as HTMLImageElement;
  var img0 = new Image(); 
  
  img0.src = img0Src;
  
  img0.onload = function () {
    ctx1.drawImage(img0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't saving the image data in local storage, it's saving the path and causing another web request for https://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/fxxj3ttftm5ltcqnto1o4baovyl.png